# Stateless Sessions with Spring Security Saml and SP Application

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, httpsession, spring-saml

I tried to run the boot sample spring security saml boot from,
https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample

I am able to run it and integrate with identity provider.

But, I see that a session is created every time and remains persistent till the user sign's out.

I am using Resource based services with spring boot and so do not want the overhead of sessions.

I tried adding the below line to the configure method,
 http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

But, with this setting I am always being asked to login to Identity Provider.

If I login, it comes back to the page asking me to login again in a loop.

I am not sure if this is the correct behaviour when disabling sessions.

Can anyone provide me with the right approach to use stateless sessions with spring security saml extension and a service provider application.

Thanks,

Sri

Answer (score 2):

You need a session for sure for the SAML authentication part, so you have 2 options:

1) Have 2 different security contexts in you your applications, one for SAML Authentication and one for your stateless services. Not sure how would you authenticate your services but It'd have to have some sort of token auth for it to be stateless.
You can define 2 `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`and override the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. Then use `http.requestMatchers("/saml/**")` in the saml config and `http.requestMatchers("/service/**")` in your service config and everything under `/saml` will go through saml auth and everything under `/service` will go through whatever else you have.

2) Add more filter(s) to the SAML configuration (before the saml filters) so that it works with a different kind of auth (token based for instance) and as far as this filter(s) can generate a valid `Authentication` before the saml filters you should be good.

You can also check out this library: https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml to simplify your SAML configuration

Comment: Hi Sri, We have the same requirement in our project. Could you please tell me how did you implement it.  Thanks in advance. Kitty

Comment: Hi Sam, I have tried the same way you have suggested, after saml authentication, when user makes the next call with different endpoint, spring is allowing it to hit the endpoint. But the second endpoint is stateless one and I have created a filter and using different logic to make it authenticate success. Logic used in the filter is of no use now as spring is considering it as already authenticated. To solve this  in the 
 rest end point implementation (/saml/**) I am invalidating the session. But I feel this is not the correct way. please tell me if there is any better solution. -Kitty

Comment: I think what is left unclear from 1) is how to stop spring from using the jsessionid it created during SAML authentication from being used under `"/service/**"`, it seems spring sees jsessionid and assumes the request is authenticated for all places.

Comment: At the end of the day spring security just adds a chain of filters to each request that are executed, one of them is the session filter. You can modify the chain and plugin your own conditional session filter or have different “realms” which are basically different filter chains for different paths, you can define those using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Answer (score 2):

To enable SAML in stateless you will need:

- To set the SAMLMessageStorageFactory to an empty one.
- Ensure the SAML filter is after your remember me filter.
- Actually enable stateless and configure your remember me service as usual.

Note that doing this means you have no JSESSIONID, which means spring will no longer record the original requested URL and so can't handle redirecting you back to that later. (Proposed work around for this later).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class YourSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    /**
     * Since SAML is being used under a stateless mode, we can not use the default
     * Message Storage factory as it uses http sessions. Instead we have to use
     * the EmptyStorageFactory().
     * 
     */
    @Bean
    public SAMLMessageStorageFactory sAMLMessageStorageFactory() {
        return new EmptyStorageFactory();
    }

    
@Autowired(required=false)
    @Qualifier("samlFilter")
    FilterChainProxy samlFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       ...
       // Only try to do SAML stuff after we have tried to authenticate the user.
       http.addFilterAfter(samlFilter, RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.class)
       
       // (Optional part if you want redirects)
       // Just before we get to the samlFilter if we have not yet authenticated we
       // may set a cookie storing the location to which we should redirect back to
       // when all is said and done.
       http.addFilterBefore(setRedirectCookieForPostSAMLAction, samlFilter.getClass());
       // On SAML auth success, apply the redirect from the cookie. 
       sAMLProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new ReadRedirectCookieForSAMLSuccessHandler());
       // (End Optional part)
       ...
       // Don't forget to enable your token based remember me service
       // Also don't forget to set stateless
       http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

Finally if you do want to support some form of redirecting do this:

- Have your UI redirect you to some special URL and record the URL to go to in the GET param. E.g. if you turn up at `/secure.html`, the UI would redirect you to `/saml-redirect.html?redirectTo=/secure.html`.
- Create a filter `SetRedirectCookieForPostSAMLAction` which if the user is going to `saml-redirec.html` and is not authenticated sets a cookie recording the `redirectTo` value. This filter is called before the SAML Filter redirects the user to the IDP.

```
public class setRedirectCookieForPostSAMLAction implements Filter {
   void setRedirectCookieIfRequired(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        // If the user is not authenticated and is going to the saml redirect page
        if(authentication == null && 
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml-redirect.html", null).matches(request)) {
            if(request has a redirectTo param) {
                 Set cookie "saml-redirect-post-action" to Base64(redirectTo);
            }
        }

}
}
```

- Create a success handler `ReadRedirectCookieForSAMLSuccessHandler` which will run when the user successfully logs in with SSO (configured above). This success handler just needs to redirect the user if the redirect cookie. Also it should clearing that cookie redirect cookie.

(Don't forget to check the redirect looks legit, and only goes to your app before redirecting the user.)